# How to figure out if two CGRect intersect?

Tags: iphone

In -drawRect: I want to check if the provided rect intersects with anotherRect.

I'm not good at this geometry math stuff and especially at english so what I want to say is:

If you have two sheets of paper on the desk, and one of them covers the other either completely or just a small portion, it is rectsIntersect = YES.

How to check that out for `rect` and `anotherRect`?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use `bool CGRectIntersectsRect (CGRect rect1,CGRect rect2);`

**Swift 3:**

```
public func intersects(_ rect2: CGRect) -> Bool
```

Example: `rect1.intersects(rect2)`

Comment: Here is a blog post that talks about it: http://blogs.oreilly.com/iphone/2008/12/useful-core-graphics-functions.html

Comment: Thanks Brandon, he has the correct signature (which I did not)

Comment: No problem, just didn't want someone swooping in with the correct name and taking your answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this..
While animating imageview you can get its actual frame by this:

```
[[obstacle1.layer presentationLayer] frame];
```

So, it will easily to make collision of two imageview

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect([[obstacle1.layer presentationLayer] frame], [[bgImageView.layer
    presentationLayer] frame])) 
{

    NSLog(@"Collision 1");

}
```