# Drag , drop and validate it

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, swift4, xcode9

Hi all i have a requirement  to implement the functionality for UIImage/ UIbutton to drag and drop. Also, need to validate it . If it does't match then, need to send it back on original location. 
Any resource Or succession will be help full. Thanks in advance to all

Actually i'm developing a mobile application for kid in which i need to drag the image from one location and drop it to the correct location.
And validate that dragged image match with the dropped location or not. if not than place that image on initial position

Comment: Please make your requirement clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **intersects** for collision detect btw two frames and compare both with its tag and match the image/button.

```
draggedImage.frame.intersects(droppedLocation.frame )
```

for more details [check  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714103/how-to-figure-out-if-two-cgrect-intersect)